# Can we allow user to only select one parameter at a time in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have three date columns. My report has 6 parameters: start and end date range for all three columns. Currently user has to select all date range but what if I want to allow user to only select one date range at a time. I cannot do "allow NULL values" option in the parameter because that see it as a field containing null value. I don't think it's possible to allow user to select only one parameter at a time so I'm trying an approach where there will be three parameters: one will consists of date field names. And rest two are based on date range of the field that is select from previous parameter. For example user selects a date field name from first and then date parameters will be cascaded and grab a value of date field based on the date field name that is selected in previous parameter. But I'm not sure exactly how to approach this. Any ideas?

Comment: Create a Stored Procedure, with optional Parameters , Use dynamic sql inside stored procedure, jobs a good'un.

Comment: Any example? Sorry not familiar with that

Comment: google Stored Procedure with optional parameters using dynamic SQL , plenty of stuff online....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do that in some of my reports. The first parameter is "Does the range apply to A, B, or C" and the second and third parameters are the start and end data respectively. Well, I use integers, but dates should work the same as long as you format them.

The way it works, is you set the query in your dataset to be a function, and build it as mostly a quote but with the parameter values substituted in. A typical one might be

```
= "SELECT * FROM dbo.Trips WHERE " + Parameters!WhatField.Value + " between '" + FormatDateTime(Parameters!StartDate.Value, dateformat.shortdate) + "' and '" + FormatDateTime(Parameters!EndDate.Value, dateformat.shortdate) + "'"
```

Your parameter "WhatField" is a drop down list with 3 permitted values, make the value be the field name and the display be what your user wants to see as a description of the field.

I think you have to set the query for delayed evaluation somewhere (but I can't spot where right now, so maybe I'm mis-remembering), and you should set default values for your parameters that don't crash your report, but other than that it's fairly straightforward.

Oh, and to make the query a function it's just like a text query but hit the button to the right of the text box - it has a "fx" on it

If you need an even more complex query, you can put the whole query text in code (off the report properties) and call that function from the "fx" button to generate your query string.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't tried this. I tried a different approach I created another field and called it datetype whenever the date1 field is not null I assigned a name "datetype1" union all with rest of the fields and then union all and assigned "All" value. And then I created parameter of datetype and allowed user to pick which datetype they want and the cascaded it so the date range parameter is depended on the datetype para. It worked but the only thing that didn't work is 'All' datetype.

Comment: @user3483150 If you have a really complex query you can build it entirely within code stored on your form - put it in a report level function and call the function from the dataset "query text" page. You can even have it hit different tables there, you just have to be sure all the returned fields have exactly the same names and types.